# Deploying a resource file on iOS with Qt

Tags: c++, ios, qt, file, ios-simulator

I have written an application in c++ that reads information from a file and prints it to the application GUI.

It works fine as long as i have a "normal" file-system.

Now i'd like to deploy my app (with a modified Qt-GUI) to iOS, but i don't know how to deploy the file together with my app onto the iphone-simulator.

**My question is:**

 How can i deploy a file together with my app in QT?

Comment: Have you read up on http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html ?

Comment: @Aerius Now i did! It works fine with the qrc file! But now i have the problem that i can't use `fopen()` to open the file!